# while loop using

Tags: r

For assignment we need to use R and I am a rookie with R, so all help is welcome.

I have tried everything I could possibly find but it will not work, I added a example of a code I have, I know it is possibly totally wrong but so you can see what the if-statement is and from which table it comes.

```
no_sus <- numeric()
 x<-0 
while (x <= 10)
 { print(crimes$id)
if   (crimes$outcome_status_category == "Investigation complete; no suspect identified" )    
} x = x+1 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without any loop :

```
no_sus <- head(crimes$id[crimes$outcome_status_category %in% "Investigation complete; no suspect identified"], 10)
```

However, if you have to use a `while` loop, you can do :

```
no_sus <- numeric(10)
x<-0 
i <- 1
while (x <= 10) { 
  if  (crimes$outcome_status_category[i] %in% "Investigation complete; no suspect identified") {
   x = x+1 
   no_sus[x] <- crimes$outcome_status_category[i]
  }
  i <- i +1
}
```

Comment: When i use this code I am getting a error: Error in if (crimes$outcome_status_category[i] == "Investigation complete; no suspect identified") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>  How should I fix this error? thanks in advance

Comment: @Engebrade34 Try updated answer with `%in%`.